# Semi-orthogonal decomposition of derived category of Calabi-Yau manifolds?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, derived-categories

Let $X$ is a smooth projective variety over some field with trivial canonical bundle $\omega_X\cong\mathscr{O}_X$. In the book *Fourier-Mukai transforms of AG* by D. Huybrechts, he claim that there are no non-trivial semi-orthogonal decomposition of $D^b(X)$ (Exercise 8.8). Why? We may use the Serre duality? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the Serre functor on $D^b(X)$ for $X$ a smooth projective variety is given by $(-)\otimes \omega_X [n]$, where $\omega_X$ is the canonical sheaf. In particular, for a Calabi-Yau variety, the Serre functor is just the shift functor $[n]$. Suppose there was a nontrivial SOD $\langle \mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}\rangle = D^b(X)$. Then for all $A\in \mathcal{A}$ and $B\in \mathcal{B}$ we must have $\text{Hom}(B,A[i]) = 0$ for all $i$. However, Serre duality (stated using the Serre functor) states
$$
\mathrm{Hom}(B,A[i]) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(A[i],S(B))^* =\mathrm{Hom}(A[i],B[n])^*=\mathrm{Hom}(A,B[n-i])^*.
$$
Consequently, $\mathrm{Hom}(A,B[j]) =0$ for all $j$. This implies that $\langle \mathcal{B},\mathcal{A}\rangle = D^b(X)$ is also a semiorthogonal decomposition. So, $\langle \mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}\rangle$ is an orthogonal decomposition, which is not possible for $X$ connected (which is a necessary hypothesis - it depends on your definition of variety).